# How to have two-way data binding on a property of an object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select2

Let's say I have below object

```
var objs = [{"someKey":"test"}, {"someKey","test2"}]
```

I want to have two-way data binding to `some.model.name` in my ng-model which should only care about values of the `objs`.

```
<ui-select ng-model="some.model.name">
```

Also, I like to select objs by value

```
<ui-select-match class="ui-select-match">
{{$select.selected.value}}
</ui-select-match>
```

I am going through the `objs` and display `someKey`'s value

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="myKey.value as myKey in objs track by myKey.value">
<div ng-bind="myKey.value">
```

The problem is that `some.model.name` do not have value in it while `objs` have and I wonder if is there any way that I can flatten the `objs` in ng-repeat so they only have values of the keys?

[sample code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2096d5e8c4866df08faa2ac9d2008166)

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or gist of the code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: This will add obj in some.model.name    `<ui-select-choices repeat=" myKey in objs track by myKey.value">
<div ng-bind="myKey.value"></ui-select-choices>`

Comment: spin up a plunker and we can troubleshoot

Comment: thanks, I have added gist sample code